# How to pull data from one excel cell into html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have one excel file which will be filled by many users. How can I pull data from cell B2 for example, to be automatically placed somewhere in HTML page using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try threating the excel as .csv like [in this tutorial](https://www.js-tutorials.com/jquery-tutorials/reading-csv-file-using-jquery/) or [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxZgPbzk4dU) instead of calling a local file call the excel by url
CSV libraries are mostly compatible.
Hope that will be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

You need to place that excel sheet in a database first(SQL specially as it's a relational database)and from there you can call that row using Http method easily via JS.